# Python Class in function

Tags: python, function, class

I have really annoying issue with python. I would like to do some instruction in function, code work without function but it does nothing in function. As below:

[image: Picture1]

Could anyone help?
It doesnt work:

```
def total():
    obiekt = Preference2('202211', 'DAYS')
    obiekt.dates()
    obiekt.pipeline()
    print(vars(obiekt))
    obiekt_n = Natural('202211', 'DAYS')
    obiekt_n.dates()
    obiekt_n.natural()
    df_natural = obiekt_n.Natural
    df_natural.set_index(['CUSTOMERID','MONTHID','YEARID'], inplace = True)
    obiekt_gen = GeneralKPI('202211', 'DAYS')
    obiekt_gen.dates()
    obiekt_gen.general()
    df_general = obiekt_gen.General
    df_general.set_index(['CUSTOMERID','MONTHID','YEARID'], inplace = True)
    
    return (df_natural, df_general, obiekt.df)
    #return reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on= ['CUSTOMERID','MONTHID','YEARID'], how='outer'), data_frames).fillna(np.nan)
```

It work:

```
obiekt = Preference2('202211', 'DAYS')
obiekt.dates()
obiekt.pipeline()
print(vars(obiekt))
```

Comment: Could you remove the screenshot and post the code directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Just call the function after it is created
def fun():
   obiekt = Preference2("202211","DAYS")
   obiekt.dates()
   obiekt.pipeline()
   print(vars(obiekt))

fun()
```

Comment: I know I have to call function. What I'am saying is that the function does nothing though the same code witout function works fine.